# Owner-draw listboxes in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm quite new to wxpython and I have a question:

I need to have a listbox-like control which enables me to:

- feed it a list of items; each items contains a string representation and an image **of varying size**.
- display this list in two ways:

  - as a regular list box,
  - as a vertical list of these image.

I remember that in Delphi you could mark a ListBox as an owner-drawn control, and you had to implement the logic to
- draw the single item
- return your custom items's height.

Is there a way to create an owner-drawn list box in wxpython?

Thanks, Massimiliano

Comment: Hi, I think you can try and hack wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl to do what you want.

Comment: sounds like what I'm looking for. Will try it on Linux...

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself: after some research, I've found that [wx.VListBox](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.VListBox.html) **exactly** fits my needs.

It exposed two methods to be overridden, [OnMeasureItem](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.VListBox.html#wx.VListBox.OnMeasureItem) and [OnDrawItem](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.VListBox.html#wx.VListBox.OnDrawItem), which allow for the same behavior found on Delphi's List Box. Works nicely both on Windows and Linux, too.

**wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl**, while *extremely flexible*, is an overkill for my needs.